# How to drop a unique constraint on a column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, ddl

This is my database table

```
CREATE TABLE cart (
  id           UUID      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  shop_user_id UUID UNIQUE
);
```

And when I try to delete the `UNIQUE` constraint on `shop_user_id` I get the sql `42601 error`

This is the query I use to delete the unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE cart DROP UNIQUE shop_user_id;
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To find the name of the unique constraint, run

```
SELECT conname
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE conrelid = 'cart'::regclass
  AND contype = 'u';
```

Then drop the constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE cart DROP CONSTRAINT cart_shop_user_id_key;
```

Replace `cart_shop_user_id_key` with whatever you got from the first query.

Comment: Tried. But can't. Because shop_user_id is the column name and not constraint name

Comment: select * from information_schema.table_constraints;
Find the constraint. Make sure to drop it from the table, then drop the unique value.

Comment: I ran select * from information_schema.table_constraints; This still shows the constraint name in there. But the problem is how to drop it?

Comment: @GhostCat Only moderators can delete comments, so the best way to get comments cleaned up is to flag them.

Comment: You can always delete your own comments. And when two people have a conversation, do you really think you need a moderator to get that cleaned up? Seriously: these people have a ton of requests coming in daily. Don't waste their time on something that can be resolved by everyone just getting his own things sorted out.

Comment: Does not work always:
select * from pg_indexes where  indexname = 'train_on_track_history_unique';
returns index train_on_track_history_unique  for table train_on_track_history, schema edr

# alter table edr.train_on_track_history drop constraint train_on_track_history_unique;
constraint "train_on_track_history_unique" of relation "train_on_track_history" does not exist

#drop index train_on_track_history_unique; 
does not exist

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
    CREATE TABLE teachers( teacher_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(250) UNIQUE NOT NULL);


select * from information_schema.table_constraints;

ALTER TABLE teachers DROP CONSTRAINT teachers_email_key;
```

Comment: I like this answer as an addendum to the accepted answer, since the table_constraints view provides a much more human readable result.